# Graphing individual marginal effects in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a probit model and I'm trying to compute and plot the marginal effects of a continuous variable for all the observations in the sample.

I'm using Stata and I have five independent variables. The variable for which I would like to compute marginal effects for all individuals takes 9 possible integer values (0 to 8), and I treat it as continuous (not as a factor variable). The most common command for marginal effects seems to be margins:

```
margins, dydx(x) at(x=(0(1)8))
marginsplot
```

This command doesn't do what I would like to do. It seems to compute marginal effects for all individuals with `x=0, x=1` and so forth and then average them for each value of x. The output I get reports a marginal effect and a standard error for each value of x.

I would like to obtain the marginal effect of x for each individual in the sample. Two individuals for whom `x=0` should have different marginal effects if the other variables in the model take different values for these observations. How can compute and plot these effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can estimate the model, `predict`, change x with `replace`, and `predict` again. Then you can calculate the differences between the two predictions to get the marginal effects. You can change x by 1 or by a small amount epsilon (which will approximate what margins calculates much better). The first version will obviously be larger.

Here's an example using the cars data:

```
set more off
sysuse auto, clear
keep foreign mpg rep78 make

clonevar orig_rep78 = rep78

probit foreign mpg rep78
margins, dydx(rep78)

predict phat, pr

replace rep78 = rep78 + 1
predict phat_plus_one, pr
gen double finite_diff = phat_plus_one - phat

replace rep78 = orig_rep78 + 0.01
predict phat_plus_eps, pr

gen double eps_diff = (phat_plus_eps - phat)/.01

drop rep78
rename orig_rep78 rep78

tw (scatter finite_diff mpg) (scatter eps_diff mpg)

sum *_diff
```

You can see that the eps version matches the margins output more closely. You might want to see how sensitive your estimates are to different values of epsilon.

I don't know what sort of graph you had in mind, so I just plotted the MEs against the other regressor. You can see that the ME is increasing in mpg, which makes sense since the index function coefficients are all positive. The low values for mpg above 30 make sense since the predicted probability is already near 1, so additional repairs can't raise it all that much.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I'm not sure I understand how it works, though. 
If I change x to 0 and then to 1 for all individuals and compute the difference, and do the same for the other values of x, I will end up with many more marginal effects than observations (the sample size times 8?).
Would it be possible to estimate one marginal effect for each individual by computing the difference in probabilities with x and x-1, for instance?
Apologies if I'm not being clear.

Comment: I think I see what you had in mind. My original answer was for a related question, but the principle was largely the same.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much!
One last question, if you don't mind: how small would I have to make epsilon to approximate as close as possible Stata's margins computations? In other words, how small is the epsilon used by Stata when approximating derivatives? Thanks. :-)

Comment: Stata actually calculates analytic derivatives, so there's no equivalent. The epsilon is technically going to zero. Take a look at section 5.7 of [Numerical Recipes in C](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html) for an idea of how to decrease the the error. In any case, since your x is integer-valued, the finite difference method seems more appropriate.

Comment: I see. And yes, the finite difference method does indeed seem better in this case. Thank you very much for your help and for the reference.